# JSF 2.0 dynamic attributes without creating new components

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

How do you add new attributes to a component that doesn't define those attributes without creating your own.

I want to do something like this

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{manager.saveNew}" value="#{i18n['School.create']}" secured="true" />
```

or at least, a way to allow the developer to assign the secure attribute.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `f:attribute` inside your `h:commandButton`.

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{manager.saveNew} 
                 value="#{i18n['School.create']}">
     <f:attribute name="secured" value="true" />
</h:commandButton>
```

And in your action method:

```
public void saveNew(ActionEvent event) {
   String secured = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("secured");
}
```

Here is a [comprehensive tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html) on this topic.