# Refactoring a DataTable with a large number of attributes

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've got [a data table](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) with 17 attributes. The table can be rendered in two modes: with row selection enabled and without it.

```
<p:dataTable selection="#{isDefaultSelectionMode ? null : widget.selected}" />
```

It doesn't work because `selection` expects a reference to a property to be able to set/get it.

1. I could create a dummy property `widget.ignored` and it's going to work. I don't like this for the obvious reason.

   ```
   <p:dataTable selection="#{isDefaultSelectionMode ? widget.ignored : widget.selected}" />
   ```
2. I could split the table into two separate templates. I would exclude `selection` from one and duplicate 16 other attributes. It's not a good one, either.

I am looking for an elegant solution to either make the attribute optional (not to render it under some condition) or to avoid defining a dummy property.

I am new to JSF and PrimeFaces, feel free to correct. Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712364/jsf-2-0-dynamic-attributes-without-creating-new-components ?

Comment: It is not **just** about custom attributes. It is about **dynamic** attributes as well. Try if it works, it might not, but it might... I never needed it and have currently no time to try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231951/what-is-fattribute-used-for-in-this-example

Comment: But then in combination with a  `c:if` around it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474926/how-not-to-set-an-attribute-of-a-component-inside-a-composite-component-if-it-is/33475114#33475114

Comment: Correct, that is why I removed that and just referenced the c:if like used in the referred question)

Comment: You can create an answer yourself if you like, just refer to the other Q/A as well and I'll upvote yours ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I didn't have to apply any of my terrible workarounds.

As suggested by @Kukeltje (thank you) and the links he provided, I defined the attribute conditionally

```
<c:if test="#{isDefaultSelectionMode}">
    <f:attribute name="selection" value="#{widget.selected}"/>
</c:if>
```

For more details, visit these questions:

- [JSF 2.0 dynamic attributes without creating new components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712364)
- [How not to set an attribute of a component inside a composite component if it is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474926)
- [What is f:attribute used for in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231951)